# How to return a relative URL from ASP.NET's GetUrlHelper()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, restful-url, asp.net-web-api-routing

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 website I'm using Web API to return JSON-formatted resources including links for authorized actions (e.g., DELETE). To create these links I'm using the GetUrlHelper() extension method on the HttpRequestMessage...

```
_httpRequest.GetUrlHelper().Link( routeName, routeValues );
```

My concern is that the string returned from Link() is a fully qualified URL (it includes the `https://example.com/...`) when all I think I need is the relative URL (just the `/my/resource`). Currently, I've got a server problem where our production environment is adding http when it should be https, which doesn't work. I can fix that separately, but it raises the question, should I just supply a relative URL? And if so, **is there a better way of getting a relative URL than trimming off the root part of the UrlHelper.Link()-generated URL?**

Edit:
After consulting Richardson's & Ruby's meritorious [RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do), I believe more firmly that a relative URL is wholly appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the `PathAndQuery` on Uri help you?

Example: `(new Uri(_httpRequest.GetUrlHelper().Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Values", p1="abc" }))).PathAndQuery`...this would give you like `/my/resource?p1=abc`

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely the cleanest way to pull out the relative from the absolute. What I was really hoping for was a way to get the relative URL directly from the framework without having it interrogate the request object for scheme, etc. But I'll take what I can get.